Adjucent similar values grouping in SAP Viz frame column chart
Here I am facing an issue where Vizframes column chart grouping the adjacent similar values on x-axis,into one data label as below screen for temperature values where I want to remove that and use that value for each column without merging/grouping.
<viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed2' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Temperature"/>

Here is my XML:
<viz:VizFrame height="25rem" width="100%" class="graphborder" 
     id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
     vizType='column' vizProperties="{title: {text: 'Usage Trend'}}" destroyLegendGroup="true">
    <viz:dataset>
        <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{JsonModel>/graphDtls}">
            <viz.data:dimensions>
                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Meter Read Type" value="{JsonModel>Istablart}" />
                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Period" value="{JsonModel>Period}"/>
                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Temperature" value="{JsonModel>Temperature}" />
            </viz.data:dimensions>
            <viz.data:measures>
                <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="KWh/Therms" value="{JsonModel>Consumption}"/>
            </viz.data:measures>
        </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
    </viz:dataset>
    <viz:feeds>
        <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="KWh/Therms"/>
        <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed2' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Temperature"/>
        <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Period"/>
        <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed3' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Meter Read Type"/>
    </viz:feeds>
    <viz:dependents>
        <viz:Popover id="idPopOver"></viz:Popover>
    </viz:dependents>
</viz:VizFrame>

Attachment screen red highlighted:

